# how to explicitly defining the type in TypeScript and use it in function signatures etc

Tags: typescript, rxjs, typescript-typings

I try to write custom rxjs filter by following official guide wiht:

```
const myFilter = (key: string) => <T>(source: Observable<T>) =>
  new Observable<T>(observer => {
    return source.subscribe({
      next(x) {
          x = x.data.values.find(item: => item.description === key);
          observer.next(x);
      },
      error(err) { observer.error(err); },
      complete() { observer.complete(); }
    });
  });
```

However getting 'TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'T'.'

I have found workaround by using 'any':

```
const newObj: any = x;
x = newObj.data.values.find((item: any) => item.description === key);
```

However looking for solution where 'myFilter' will understand 'data' object so dot-notation to access the x object can be used without TypeScript errors and 'any' workarounds.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `map` operator here instead of doing all of that unnecessary work?

Comment: agree however was trying to find out proper way to pass correct Type. Anyway with map and array.find there will be still an "issue" with item being any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the [Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) feature of Typescript. They have a very similar example in the docs.

You'll need an interface to use. For example:

```
interface HasDataProp {
    data: DataType;
}
```

Then you need to add a constraint on your `T` to limit the types allowed to be used:

```
const myFilter = (key: string) => <T extends HasDataProp>(source: Observable<T>) =>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! My question indeed should be more about Generic Constraints rather than function signatures.